# Display all pages on one page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to display all pages (different page templates) on one page
for ex : About , portfolio , resume , contact etc in one page
i want to display each page in a div in index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is really simple implementation, add the below code in your index.php

Modify ID for page destiny.

you have create div´s in HTML

```
       <?php $page_id = XXX;  //Page ID
       $page_data = get_page( $page_id );
       //Guardar variáveis
       $title = $page_data->post_title;
       $content = apply_filters('get_the_content', $page_data->post_content);?>
      <div id="box-title">
      <div id="titulo-publicidade">
      <?php echo $title; //Show title ?>
      </div>
     <div id="box-content">
     <?php echo $content; //Show content ?>
     </div>
     </div>
```

Good Luck.

**EDIT**

I have not tried, but it would be something like this

```
     <?php
     $mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

    foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
    $content = $page->post_content;
    if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
        continue;

    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
?>
    <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>
    <div class="entry"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
    <?php
    }   
    ?>
```

Comment: tnx for your answer , but i want to load all pages dynamiclly without using page id and display it into divs